# How do I build a Style Library for use in Silverlight Class Libraries?

Tags: silverlight, styling

I have a Silverlight application that is built from a set of Silverlight class libraries.  I would like to create a common Silverlight library that contains a set of resources used to define the styles used for all the Silverlight UI libraries.  This would be simlar to the `<Styles>'s` defined in the  node within App.xaml file.

Is this possible?  And if so, how would I implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is possible using WPF (via Dynamic Resources, [see this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC47/) and fast forward to 12:00), I don't think this is possible yet in Silverlight. The closest thing you have to this is the [themes in the Silverlight toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203&referringTitle=Home). There is a comment on that page by the team stating that you can't change themes (or resource styles) at runtime in Silverlight 2:

> unruledboy, We do not support changing themes at run-time as this is not an ability supported by the Silverlight framework.

So I think themes is the closest thing available right now.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, in a round-about way this will probably work however this seems to be a real shortcoming of the Silverlight frameworks...hmmmm....